# Visual Studio Code always uses old version of tsc

Tags: visual-studio-code, tsc

I am using typescript as a way of creating javascript for a webpage. My first attempt at using the tsc compiler produced error TS1005 about a missing ';'. This is apparently because Visual Studio Code is using an old version of tsc.

I find I have two versions on my system (discovered using where tsc in a command window):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js
C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

where the first location contains version 1.0.3.0 and the second version 2.7.2.

The only way I can get VS Code to use the latest version is to type the full path, ie

```
C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc main.ts
```

into the terminal window. When I do this there are no TS1005 errors.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain in easy terms for a VS Code novice how to set it up so it will automatically pick up the new version of tsc.

Grateful for advice.

Comment: Did you try "npm install -g typescript"?

Comment: Yes I did. That's how the version of tsc in C:\Users was created.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

However, changing the folder name "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0" to something else other than 1.0 (Example: 1.0.Original) worked for me.